# OpenCV - detecting objects based on RGB ratios

Tags: opencv

I am trying to detect objects that always have the same RGB ratios. For example, an object might have the rgb value 200 100 50 and 100 50 25.

Example image:

[image]

Here i want to detect the two orangy colors with rgbs 200 100 50 and 100 50 25.

I have been looking at Core.inrange(), but Scalars only work with static ranges to filter and i need percentual ranges. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks * 14!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is premature. Stack Overflow isn't a code or tutorial writing service, so instead of us telling you how to do it, you need to show us what you've tried and explain why it didn't work. Read "[ask]" and its linked pages and "[mcve]". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is a good read too.

Comment: I agree that this question sounds like a lazy kid that isn't bothered to look things up himself, Hence i hesitated for a while to ask. however i've literally been looking for this the entire day and haven't gotten a step further and don't know how i can figure it out..

Comment: I don't think, that this is a tutorial or code request. With this approach to everyone who just needs to point the right direction, this site would sooner  or later become something, that is against its original purpose. However, you have to provide more informations - what exactly are you trying to achieve? what objects? Where? (video,image) What language you use? And yes, if you already tried some code, provide that code and describe what did not work etc. Read how to ask as mentioned above

Comment: If you agree that it seems like you haven't looked anything up, then you need to show us what you did. Evidence of effort is important. Tell us where you looked and why those didn't help, or, show us what you tried. A whole day isn't a long time to research; As the final link in my above comment says, try, try, try and as a last resort ask. Then, when you ask, provide us what we need, which is discussed in "[ask]" and the pages it links to.

Comment: In order to answer the question correctly, we'd have to write a tutorial because there is no way to gauge programming experience level in the question itself. A code sample would help us do that, but nothing is given. To "Is there a way to do this?" we could say "yes" and leave a broad question with a broad answer, but that isn't what SO is for; We want detailed questions. And, SO's original purpose remains; It's an online community managed reference site, and to provide useful content we have to have some guidelines for what is asked and how it's asked. [meta] is the place for those.

Comment: I thought it would be best to to keep it to the core, but ill try to explain it better now

Comment: You should tag this question with the programming language you are using. Opencv has multiple interfaces, and by adding the language tag,  this question will be visible to users who view the feed of questions for that specific language.